# Free charges and boundary conditions

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, boundary-conditions, dielectric

I'm having some trouble with the following problem:

> Consider a plate of a dielectric material homogeneous and isotropic with a dielectric constant equal to er= 2 , in the outside we have a uniform electric field E= 100v\m , that form an angle alpha with the x axis, determine the  Electric field in the dielectric and the surface density of the polarization:
>
> [image]

My question is: in order to solve the first question the book uses the relation
$$(\mathbf D_2−\mathbf D_1)⋅\hat{\mathbf n}=\sigma,$$
with $D_2$ and $D_1$ are the normal flux density component, and they consider that the free charge $\sigma =0$, because the surface is between a dielectric and a vacuum so there is no free charge are there, and the electric field inside the dielectric is equal to 
$$
\mathbf E_d=\frac{E}{\epsilon_r}\cos(\alpha)\mathbf u_x + E\sin(\alpha) \mathbf u_y
$$
where $\mathbf u_x$ and $\mathbf u_y$ are unit vectors of the $x$ and $y$ axis.

But my question is: do we also have the following relationship $D=\epsilon_0E_d\epsilon_r$ it means that the free charges are not null! so how can we assume that they are null and not null at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free charge in a dielectric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285227)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Free charge in a dielectric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285227/free-charge-in-a-dielectric)

Comment: no the question was completely different, thanks for your contribution though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my confusion:
the first free charges are those between the dielectric surface and the vacuum 
in this case they are null.
the second type of free charges: are those who generated the field and caused the polarization of the dielectric and they are completely different from the first type! so there is no contradiction.